# How can I fix YouCompleteMe's wrong error highlighting of "cout" usage?

Tags: c++, vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I've been trying to get YouCompleteMe set up on my machine, and I'm mostly there, except for a small problem. When I use a `cout` for a simple `cout << "Hello world!" << endl;`, YCM highlights the `cout`, the first `<<`, and the string as an error, telling me: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'int') and 'const char *').

I know my program is correct. It compiles and runs. What could be causing this behavior?

Let me know if I left out any information.

Thanks!

Edit: my .ycm_extra_conf.py file is this:

```
import os
import ycm_core

# These are the compilation flags that will be used in case there's no
# compilation database set (by default, one is not set).
# CHANGE THIS LIST OF FLAGS. YES, THIS IS THE DROID YOU HAVE BEEN LOOKING FOR.
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-stdlib=libc++',
'-std=c++11',
'-x', 'c++',
# This path will only work on OS X, but extra paths that don't exist are not
# harmful
'-isystem', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include'
'-isystem', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include'
'-isystem', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include'
'-isystem', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks'
'-isystem', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers',
'-isystem', '../llvm/include',
'-isystem', '../llvm/tools/clang/include',
'-I','.',
'-I','./ClangCompleter',
]

# Set this to the absolute path to the folder (NOT the file!) containing the
# compile_commands.json file to use that instead of 'flags'. See here for
# more details: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html
#
# Most projects will NOT need to set this to anything; you can just change the
# 'flags' list of compilation flags. Notice that YCM itself uses that approach.
compilation_database_folder = ''

if compilation_database_folder:
    database = ycm_core.CompilationDatabase( compilation_database_folder )
else:
    database = None


def DirectoryOfThisScript():
    return os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )


def MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, working_directory ):
    if not working_directory:
        return list( flags )
    new_flags = []
    make_next_absolute = False
    path_flags = [ '-isystem', '-I', '-iquote', '--sysroot=' ]
    for flag in flags:
        new_flag = flag

        if make_next_absolute:
            make_next_absolute = False
            if not flag.startswith( '/' ):
                new_flag = os.path.join( working_directory, flag )

        for path_flag in path_flags:
            if flag == path_flag:
                make_next_absolute = True
                break

            if flag.startswith( path_flag ):
                path = flag[ len( path_flag ): ]
                new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join( working_directory, path )
                break
        if new_flag:
            new_flags.append( new_flag )
    return new_flags


def FlagsForFile( filename ):
    if database:
        # Bear in mind that compilation_info.compiler_flags_ does NOT return a
        # python list, but a "list-like" StringVec object
        compilation_info = database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )
        final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute(compilation_info.compiler_flags_, compilation_info.compiler_working_dir_ )
    else:
        # relative_to = DirectoryOfThisScript()
        relative_to = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
        final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, relative_to )

    return {
        'flags': final_flags,
        'do_cache': True
    }
```

Comment: Have you included the proper header and added the using declaration/directive?

Comment: Seems like you forgot to add compilation flags into your `.ycm_extra_conf.py` file

Comment: @DennisS Alright, I've added a .ycm_extra_conf.py file, and added it as the global fallback in ~/.vimrc, but I have no idea where to start with the compiler flags. So far I have `'-Wall',
'-std=c++11',
'-stdlib=libc++',
'-x', 'c++',
'-isystem', '/usr/lib/c++/v1'
`

Comment: @HeliosPanoptes Are you receiving a confirmation request from vim then you trying to open any file from your C++ project? Something like `Found /path/to/file/.ycm_extra_conf.py. Load?`

Comment: @DennisS I didn't receive a confirmation request, but I think that's because it's the global fallback. It's definitely working, just screwing up a little on the standard libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot commas on the end of the lines telling YCM where to find the libraries. The corrected flags read:

```
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-stdlib=libc++',
'-std=c++11',
'-x', 'c++',
#'-x', 'c++-header'
# This path will only work on OS X, but extra paths that don't exist are not
# harmful
'-isystem', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include',
'-isystem', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include',
'-isystem', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include',
'-isystem', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks',
'-isystem', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers',
'-isystem', '../llvm/include',
'-isystem', '../llvm/tools/clang/include',
'-I','.',
'-I','./ClangCompleter',
]
```

Anyways, I learned a lot from all of the googling I did, so it's not a complete loss. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!